# Elegant way to convert string of Array of Arrays into a Javascript array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an ajax request that returns a list of values like this:

```
"[-5, 5, 5], [-6, 15, 15], [7, 13, 12]"
```

I need it to be a javascript array with numbers:

```
[[-5, 5, 5], [-6, 15, 15], [7, 13, 12]]
```

I tried to replace the '[' and ']' for a '|' and then split by '|' and foreach item split by ',' and add them to an array, but this is **not** elegant at all.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Define elegant? Most string manipulations aren't really pretty.

Comment: Using split + for loop where perhaps match would do is likely not elegant or pretty. ;-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert that string into an array, as long as you wrap it in some brackets manually first:

```
var value = "[-5, 5, 5], [-6, 15, 15], [7, 13, 12]";
var json = JSON.parse("[" + value + "]");

console.log(json);
```

I would suggest correcting the output at the server if possible, though.

Comment: Thanks for the fast & elegant response!

Comment: that is pretty, :)

Comment: This does not accept string like this "[Name, 26], [Name2, 45]" Any idea how to do it?

Comment: @Kishan Depends greatly on the context and what can appear in place of `Name` - probably in this case you just want to do something like create a 2D array by extracting all the contents of `[ ]` pairs and then exploding on commas.

Comment: Yes, name can be a string value which is giving me an error with JSON.parse. I am using `eval` as last resort but I heard that eval is not a good choice?

Comment: @Kishan Not sure eval would work here, because those variables would have to be declared to be resolvable? I mean, they won't be treated as strings but rather pointers to variables called `Name`, `Name2` etc.

Comment: OK I am doing something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19418274/2286762 on `['Name', 15] , ['Name2', 34]` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is stupid in practice -- absolutely use `JSON.parse` as others have said -- but in the interest of having fun with regular expressions, here you go:

```
function getMatches(regexp, string) {
  var match, matches = [];
  while ((match = regexp.exec(string)) !== null)
    matches.push(match[0]);
  return matches;
}

function parseIntArrays(string) {
  return getMatches(/\[[^\]]+\]/g, string)
    .map(function (string) {
      return getMatches(/\-?\d+/g, string)
        .map(function (string) { 
          return parseInt(string); 
        });
    });
}

parseIntArrays("[-5, 5, 5], [-6, 15, 15], [7, 13, 12]");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating the data, and you trust it, just use `eval`:

```
var string = "[-5, 5, 5], [-6, 15, 15], [7, 13, 12]"

var arrays = eval('[' + string + ']');
```

Alternatively, start returning well-formed JSON.

Comment: In before 'eval is evil'.

Comment: @upvoter There's really no good reason to use `eval` when the string is *also* valid JSON, please downvote me instead.

Answer (score 1):

In a function

```
var strToArr = function(string){ return JSON.parse('[' + string + ']')}

console.log(strToArr("[-5, 5, 5], [-6, 15, 15], [7, 13, 12]"));
```

Comment: Shouldn't that function be named `stringToArr`?

Comment: @Jashwant Don't look at me.

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "[-5, 5, 5], [-6, 15, 15], [7, 13, 12]";
var arr = [];
var tmp = string.split('], ');

for (var i=0; i<tmp.length; i++) {
    arr.push(tmp[i].replace(/\[|\]/g, '').split(', '));
}
```

Typing on my iPad so I apologize in advance for any typos.