# Loading string format arrays into an array

Tags: javascript

I am getting a set of Arrays in string format from Database like

> ["#464b4e","#7ebcbd"], ["#747493","#f5f6f7"], ["#58383c","#8d8566"]

Now I need to load them into array to make an array of arrays. Using this code

```
        let imgIndicators = [];
        imgIndicators.push( obj[i]['dicatorsbg']);
        console.log(imgIndicators);
```

is creating an array like

```
["["#464b4e","#7ebcbd"], ["#747493","#f5f6f7"], ["#58383c","#8d8566"]"]
```

which as you can see is big long string item, so I tried splitting the data by `,` like

```
imgIndicators.push( obj[i]['dicatorsbg'].split(','));
```

This time code is accepting all `,` and creating an array of 6 string elemet like

```
 ["["#464b4e"", ""#7ebcbd"]", " ["#747493"", ""#f5f6f7"]", " ["#58383c"", ""#8d8566"]"]
```

How can I fix this code to create something like this?

```
 [
   ["#464b4e", "#7ebcbd"], 
   ["#747493", "#f5f6f7"], 
   ["#58383c", "#8d8566"]
]
```

Comment: do you get a JSON string or some other format? where is `'dicatorsbg'` coming from?

Comment: I guess it is  JSON string  because I have this in my PHP side `echo json_encode($products);`

Comment: Since it's a JSON (assuming $product is an array-like or object-like in php), please just follow this: 1) Post an example of the JSON, even the original one, if you can share it. 2) Post the expected result. It's not a great deal, it's just matter of parsing the JSON string, acquiring the desired value and pushing it to a new array, that's it.

Comment: does `JSON.parse` works for you or just taking the string as is into the javascript part? - with maybe wrapped into brackets? but if the last part is necessary, you do not have a valid [JSON](https://json.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really sure that the format will be correct, you can try:

```
imgIndicators = JSON.parse("[" + obj[i]['dicatorsbg'] + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy , You have to use **JSON.parse()** as shown below, shall give you your required result.

```js
//your db output string 
var yourStringArray = '["#464b4e","#7ebcbd"], ["#747493","#f5f6f7"], ["#58383c","#8d8566"]' ; 

// the array you want
var requiredArray = JSON.parse("[" + yourStringArray + "]");
```

More solutions can be found on this thread issue : [Elegant way to convert string of Array of Arrays into a Javascript array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418244/elegant-way-to-convert-string-of-array-of-arrays-into-a-javascript-array-of-arra)